# Rusty Coder - Better way to avoid soql in loop

Tags: soql, loop

I haven't had to write any code in a few years now and I have to believe I am not using the best approach to avoid a SOQL query in the loop. I am doing a query outside of the loop and then iterating over the list with an IF statement to find my records. What is the better way of doing this?

```
trigger sec_Pri_Mgmt_Trigger on Security_Privacy_Management__c (after update) {
    
*removed code*

    list <BCS__c> hubs = new list<BCS__c>([Select ID,Name,User__c from BCS__c]); 
    
    for (Security_Privacy_Management__c  SPM : Trigger.new) {

            
            //system.debug('Entered SPM loop');
            
            //Get Supervisor Hub details
            BCS__c supdetails;
            for(BCS__c bcs:hubs){
                if(bcs.id == spm.Supervisor_Name__c){
                    supdetails = bcs;
                }
            }
            
            //Get Employee Hub details
            BCS__c empdetails;
            for(BCS__c bcs:hubs){
                if(bcs.id == spm.BCInsourcing_Employee__c){
                    empdetails = bcs;
                }
            }
            
            *removed code*
...
```

Comment: build a map from hubs that is Id => BCS__c

Comment: Start [here](https://ktema.org/articles/quick-look-computational-complexity-apex/).

Answer (score 3):

You're searching a record with a specific Id in the `hubs` list, so in order to reduce the complexity you need a data structure that let you pair an Id to an sObject. That data structure should be optimized to search and retrieve a value by its key in constant time. Therefore a `Map<Id, sObject>` is what you want.
Map has a [constructor](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_map.htm#apex_System_Map_ctor) that take a list of sObject as input, so you could pass the static SOQL on `BCS__c` and get an instance of `Map<Id, BCS__c>`.
Then you could replace those for-loops with a `map.get()`:

```java
Map<Id, BCS__c> hubs = new Map<Id, BCS__c>([SELECT Name, User__c FROM BCS__c]); 
    
for (Security_Privacy_Management__c spm : Trigger.new) {

    //Get Supervisor Hub details
    BCS__c supdetails = hubs.get(spm.Supervisor_Name__c);
    
    //Get Employee Hub details
    BCS__c empdetails = hubs.get(spm.BCInsourcing_Employee__c);
}
```